# Why am I getting a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I posted this code earlier, but was told to clean it up and repost.  The errors I'm getting are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at FVolume.createCustomers(FVolume.java:74)
    at FVolume.<init>(FVolume.java:21)
    at FVolume.main(FVolume.java:270)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FVolume extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;
    private JPanel Customers;

    JTextArea NameTextCustomers, ExistTextCustomers, NameTextContractors, ExistTextContractors;

    public FVolume(){
        setTitle("Volume Calculator");
        setSize (300, 200);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        getContentPane().add( topPanel );

        createCustomers();

        jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        jtabbedPane.addTab("Customers", Customers);
        topPanel.add(jtabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
    /*      CREATE CUSTOMERS    */

    public JPanel createCustomers(){
        Customers = new JPanel();
        Customers.setLayout(null);

        NameTextCustomers = new JTextArea();
        NameTextCustomers.setBounds(10, 10, 350, 150);
        NameTextCustomers.setLineWrap(true);
        Customers.add(NameTextCustomers);

        JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
        Exit.setBounds(30,170,80,20);
        Exit.addActionListener(this);
        Exit.setBackground(Color.white);
        Customers.add(Exit);

        JButton AddCustomers = new JButton("Add Customer");
        AddCustomers.setBounds(130,170,120,20);
        AddCustomers.setBackground(Color.white);
        Customers.add(AddCustomers);

        JButton Refresh = new JButton("Refresh");
        Refresh.setBounds(260,170,80,20);
        Refresh.setBackground(Color.white);
        Customers.add(Refresh);

        ExistTextCustomers = new JTextArea();
        ExistTextCustomers.setBounds(10, 200, 350, 60);
        ExistTextCustomers.setLineWrap(true);
        Customers.add(ExistTextCustomers);

        final JTextArea custArea = new JTextArea(6, 30); 
        final JTextArea custMessage = null; 

        AddCustomers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {   
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        new Customer("Customer");
    }
        });
        Customers.add(custArea);
        Customers.add(AddCustomers);

        Customers.add(Refresh);
        Customers.add(custMessage);
        Refresh.setMnemonic('R');

        Refresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
        custMessage.setText("");
        try
        {
            File custOpen = new File("customer.txt"); 
            FileReader custAreaIn = new FileReader(custOpen); 
            custArea.read(custAreaIn, custOpen.toString()); 
            custMessage.setText("The file exists and can be read from.");
        }
        catch (IOException e3){
        custMessage.setText("The file could not be read. " + e3.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    );
        return Customers;
}
class Customer extends JFrame
{
    private String[] states = {"AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", 
            "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", 
            "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", 
            "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", 
            "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"}; 
            private JComboBox StateList = new JComboBox(states); 
            private JTextField NameText = new JTextField(25); 
            private JTextField AddressText = new JTextField(25); 
            private JTextField CityText = new JTextField(25); 
            private JTextField ZipText = new JTextField(9); 
            private JTextField PhoneText = new JTextField(10); 
            private JTextField PopMessageText = new JTextField(30); 
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

            private AddCustButtonHandler addCusHandler = new AddCustButtonHandler(); 

            public Customer(String who) 
            {
                popUpWindow (who);
            }
            public void popUpWindow(final String who) {
                final JFrame popWindow; 
                popWindow = new JFrame(who); 
                popWindow.setSize(425, 350); 
                popWindow.setLocation(100, 100); 
                popWindow.setVisible(true); 
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

                Container c = new Container(); 

                popWindow.add(c); 

                c.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

                JPanel one = new JPanel(); 
                JPanel two = new JPanel(); 
                JPanel three = new JPanel(); 
                JPanel four = new JPanel(); 
                JPanel five = new JPanel(); 
                JPanel six = new JPanel(); 

                one.add(new JLabel(who + " Name ")); 
                one.add(NameText); 
                two.add(new JLabel("Address ")); 
                two.add(AddressText); 
                three.add(new JLabel("City ")); 
                three.add(CityText); 
                four.add(new JLabel("State ")); 
                StateList.setSelectedIndex(0); 
                four.add(StateList); 
                four.add(new JLabel("ZIP")); 
                four.add(ZipText); 
                four.add(new JLabel("Phone")); 
                four.add(PhoneText); 
                JButton addwho = new JButton("Add " + who); 
                addwho.setMnemonic('A'); 
                JButton close = new JButton("Close"); 
                close.setMnemonic('C'); 
                JButton deleteFile = new JButton("Delete File"); 
                deleteFile.setMnemonic('D'); 
                five.add(addwho); 
                five.add(close); 
                five.add(deleteFile); 
                PopMessageText.setEditable(false); 
                PopMessageText.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); 

                six.add(PopMessageText); 
                c.add(one); 
                c.add(two); 
                c.add(three); 
                c.add(four); 
                c.add(five); 
                c.add(six); 

                deleteFile.setToolTipText("Delete File"); 
                addwho.setToolTipText("Add "+ who); 
                close.setToolTipText("Close");

                if (who == "Customer")
                    addwho.addActionListener(addCusHandler);
                close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        NameText.setText(""); 
                        AddressText.setText(""); 
                        CityText.setText(""); 
                        ZipText.setText(""); 
                        PhoneText.setText(""); 
                        PopMessageText.setText(""); 
                        popWindow.dispose();
                    }
                }
                );
                deleteFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        PopMessageText.setText("");
                        if (who == "Customer") {
                            File file = new File("Customer.txt"); 
                            boolean cusFileDeleted = file.delete(); 
                            if (cusFileDeleted) {
                                PopMessageText 
                                .setText("Customer file has been deleted"); 
                            } else {
                                PopMessageText 
                                .setText("There was an error in deleting file"); 
                            }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            class AddCustButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent addCusHandler) { 
                    int StateIndex; 
                    try { 
                        File file = new File("Customer.txt");
                        boolean success = file.createNewFile();
                        if (success) {
                            PopMessageText
                            .setText("Customer.txt file created file added");
                        } else if (file.canWrite()) {
                            PopMessageText
                            .setText("Writing data to Customer.txt, file added");
                        } else {
                            PopMessageText.setText("Cannot create file: Customer.txt");
                        }
                        try {
                            FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter("Customer.txt", true);
                            fileW.write(NameText.getText());
                            fileW.write(",");
                            fileW.write(AddressText.getText());
                            fileW.write(",");
                            fileW.write(CityText.getText());
                            fileW.write(",");
                            StateIndex = StateList.getSelectedIndex();
                            fileW.write(states[StateIndex]);
                            fileW.write(",");
                            fileW.write(ZipText.getText());
                            fileW.write(",");
                            fileW.write(PhoneText.getText());
                            fileW.write("\r\n");
                            fileW.close();
                            PopMessageText.setText("A new Customer has been added!");
                            FileReader fileR = new FileReader("Customer.txt");
                            BufferedReader buffIn = new BufferedReader(fileR);
                            String textData = buffIn.readLine();
                            buffIn.close();                         
                        }
                        catch (IOException e1) { 
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage(), "ERROR", 2);
                        }
                        NameText.setText(""); 
                        AddressText.setText(""); 
                        CityText.setText(""); 
                        ZipText.setText(""); 
                        PhoneText.setText(""); 
                        }
                    catch (IOException e1) { 
                    }
                }
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            }
                private void Exit_pressed(){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }


                public static void main(String[] args){
                    JFrame frame = new FVolume();
                    frame.setSize(380, 350);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
final JTextArea custMessage = null; 
...
Customers.add(custMessage);
```

What did you hope that would do? You're not allowed to pass in a null reference to the `add` method, basically.

For future reference, the clue to diagnosing this yourself is to find the first bit of the stack trace that refers to your code - which in this case is the line:

```
Customers.add(custMessage);
```

Then look what it's using (`Customers` and `custMessage`) and work out whether they're okay. In this case it's pretty clear that the value of `custMessage` is null, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Thanks, I got that part to work now.  I noticed when I click the refresh button on my GUI it doesn't work.  A whole list of errors pop up.

Comment: @Mike: Tackle one at a time, seeing what you can work out yourself, and then posting a *short* but complete program demonstrating *just* that problem in a new question. I suspect that often you'll find that the process of creating a short but complete program will lead you to the answer.